# Python numpy array return color of given index

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a function generator_from_image that takes

- Input: an image (numpy array)
- Output: a function which returns: given a index for a pixel, returns the color of that pixel.

The functions that are returned should look like the representation for images as one-dimensional lists. The return value for index 0 is the pixel in the upper left corner, the return value for the width of the image is the upper right corner, and so on.

What I tried:

```
orig_img = cv2.imread("plane.jpg")
orig_list = cvimg_to_list(orig_img)

def generator_from_image(img):
    return img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

generator = generator_from_image(orig_list)

new_list = [generator(i) for i in range(len(orig_list))]
```

Edit:

So I want the original and new picture to be the same after the operations.

Goal output (I need help with second part)

```
def rgblist_to_cvimg(lst, height, width):
"""Return a width x height OpenCV image with specified pixels."""
# A 3d array that will contain the image data
img = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), numpy.uint8)

for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        pixel = lst[y * width + x]
        img[y, x, 0] = pixel[0]
        img[y, x, 1] = pixel[1]
        img[y, x, 2] = pixel[2]

return img

def generator_from_image(img):
    pass
    #HALP PLZ

orig_img = cv2.imread("plane.jpg")
orig_list = cvimg_to_list(orig_img)

generator = generator_from_image(orig_list)

new_list = [generator(i) for i in range(len(orig_list))]

cv2.imshow('original', orig_img)
cv2.imshow('new', rgblist_to_cvimg(new_list, orig_img.shape[0], orig_img.shape[1]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: learn about indexing with numpy https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this out if you need a function

```py
def generator_from_image(img, x, y):
    return img[x][y]

# If you want to apply it on flatten image
def generator_from_flatten_image(img, index):
    return img[index]
```

If you want to make your image an one-dimensional array of RGB values then directly extract pixel color then

```py
img = cv2.imread("path/to/image")
flatten_img = img.reshape((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))
pixel_colors = [x for x in flatten_img.to_list()]
```

Comment: Hey, check my edit for clarification. I didn't get your function to work. I think generator_from_image needs a function inside that extracts the color value for the chosen pixel.